# Can one trust objective-c (non ARC) autorelease memory management mechanism?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

Consider the following (useless) program which keeps placing random NSStrings into the first 4 slots of an NSMutableArray. After the string as been replaced in the array I don't need it any longer, hence I'd like to release it, but since I created it with stringWithCString I'm not supposed to worry about its release. Somebody else will take care that, so I can go to the beach and worry about my tan instead.

Right?
Wrong: this program starts eating up a lot of memory!

Hence I must worry about memory management after all...
The solution is trivial: create the NSString with alloc and initWithCString, and then
release it manually.
My question is: am I missing something?
Do I always have to worry about memory waste when I create an object with a method which does not make me an owner of that object, and which, by consequence, somebody else is suppose to release at an "appropriate time"?

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define NBYTES 10000

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int i;
char input[100];
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

// Create 4 long strings
static char buffer[4][NBYTES];
memset( buffer[0], 'A', NBYTES );
memset( buffer[1], 'B', NBYTES );
memset( buffer[2], 'C', NBYTES );
memset( buffer[3], 'D', NBYTES );
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    buffer[i][NBYTES-1] = 0;
}

int n = 10000;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int j = random() & 0x3;   // a random integer between 0 and 3
    int k = random() & 0x3;   // a random integer between 0 and 3
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer[j] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [list replaceObjectAtIndex:k withObject:str];

    // I cannot release str since I created it with
    // stringWithCString, hence I'n not owner.
    // If I try to release str in fact I get segmentation fault
    // when [pool drain] is executed
    // [str release];
}

printf("check memory usage now\n");
fgets( input, 2, stdin );

[pool drain];
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Nothing says that you're limited to a single autorelease pool.  If you know that you're generating a lot of autoreleased objects in a loop, it's fairly normal to create a nested pool to take care of that.

Comment: Yeah... @autorelease{}

Comment: Loops are often good candidates for autorelease pools. Simply change `for (i=0; i<n; i++) {` for `for (i=0; i<n; i++) autoreleasepool {`.